# Is there a way to restore WEP connectivity in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, wep

I have to connect to a WEP Wi-Fi network with my Windows 10 laptop.

Is there a way to restore such connectivity in Windows 10 after that Microsoft decided to disable it?

Notes:

- I am completely aware of WEP security, I just want to have the choice. Why not removing open networks then?
- I still use this WEP connection because I have no choice, I need to use a hotspot on my phone making the whole thing more complicated

Comment: Can you set up the Access Point with no security (not much worse than WEP)?   I use that seven months ago with Windows 10 in a location where there was not particular danger.

Comment: @John Unfortunately I do not have any control over that AP

Comment: You could get a repeater which is capable of using a different SSID and encryption. Any dd-wrt flashable device should work.

Comment: @mashuptwice thanks, but this is just for two weeks of vacation so I am not going to invest in that (though I have some devices at home that could have been used if I have anticipated WEP in 2022). I was hoping for some magical registry setting that would bring back WEP to a Win10 laptop). I am basically doing this today with my phone as a hotspot for my laptop.

Comment: If your phone can only hotspot a WEP wireless network you're probably out of luck. Unless your phone also has the ability to tether internet to your machine through USB? Most phones can do that but I obviously don't know how old your phone is.

Comment: @Mastaxx: sorry for ot having been clear: my phone connects to the WEP network (fortunately), and then I create a WPA2 hotspot for the laptop to route that network. So I have a solution, but I would prefer to go the native way on Windows 1à by changing a miraculous and hidden parameter (to bring back WEP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enable WEP support on Windows 10 unless you decide to downgrade your Windows 10 operating system to Win10 1903, which is the version that began warning users WEP support would soon be disabled in future updates. After doing this you will need to also disable windows updates as well. Be advised, this will lessen the security of your system.

You can download all current and previous Win10 ISO installers from here:
https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php

You will need a USB stick 8GB minimum capacity. You can use Rufus to create the bootable windows installer USB:
https://rufus.ie/en/

Do backup all of your important data before doing this.